# Wifi adapter found in ubuntu after giving 777 Permision to all directory

Tags: 18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 for developement purposes.Here is the Command that i used

```
chmod 777 -R / instead of  chmod 777 -R /Documents
```

Now am not able to enable wifi driver can explain me that how to overcome from this issue.

**Thank you in Advance :)**

Comment: You'll have other problems beyond wifi.....   see answer (restore your backups, or re-install is the fastest fix; you'll have to manually restore file permissions to many files for things to work which is way more effort than restore of data, or re-install...)  ; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: @guiverc previous time same problem occured that time i used  this command. Actually this command works me on that time but not now :(
  `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"`

Comment: Reinstall. And STOP using chmod, and STOP thinking that this needs to be a wifi fix.

Answer (score 3):

> how to overcome from this issue.

Re-install your system without using the "format" option when setting up your partitions.

> Explanation

`chmod 777` is -always- the wrong method. It does not distinguish between files and directories. Most files you do not want to be set as "executable". This is likely also wrong:

```
chmod 777 -R /Documents
```

I expect you meant (unless you made a /Documents/ in root yourself) ...

```
chmod 777 -R /home/$USER/Documents
```

and even then: directories should be 750 and files should be 640 if you want the best security settings. Particularly for user owned content it is the best setting.

A correct method would be:

```
find /home/$USER/Documents/ -type d -exec chmod 0750 {} \;
find /home/$USER/Documents/ -type f -exec chmod 0640 {} \;
```

The "others" in the permissions have not a single valid reason to access your files so don't allow access. If "others" can have read access change the last 0 to a 5 and 4 in the 2 commands.

Comment: previous time same problem occured that time i used  this command. Actually this command works me on that time but not now :(
  `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"`

Comment: @PrajwalShetty I agree with this answer. Reinstall. And STOP using chmod, and STOP thinking that this needs to be a wifi fix.